# ng-repeat doesn't work inside ng-view if data comes from $http request

Tags: angularjs, http, angularjs-ng-repeat, resolve, ng-view

I'm trying to show the data that comes from an `$http` request in a template which is presented inside an `ng-view`.

I did some tests and, when the data is not coming from the resolve (ngRoute), ngRepeat works fine (e.g. if I hard code an array of objects in `$scope.products`). I've searched a lot and found a lot of examples but none with this specific issue.

here follows the code:

app.js

```
"use strict";
angular.module('himerosApp',[])
.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/index', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/welcome.html'
    })
    .when('/products/aerosois', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/products.html',
        controller: 'ProductController',
        resolve: {
            messages: function (productService) {
                return productService.getProducts();
            }
        }
    })
    .when('/social', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/social.html'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/index'
    });

}]);
```

product-controller.js

```
'use strict';
angular.module('himerosApp')
.controller("ProductController", ['$scope','messages',
function($scope, messages ) {

    $scope.products = messages;

}]);
```

product-service.js

```
angular.module('himerosApp')
.service("productService",['$http','$q',
 function( $http, $q ) {

    this.getProducts = function() {

        return $http.get("/products").then(
            function( response ) {
                return response.data;
            },
            function( response ) {

                if(!angular.isObject( response.data ) ) {
                    console.log('unknown error');
                    return ( $q.reject( "An unknown error ocurred." ) );
                }       

                console.log(response.data.message);
                return ( $q.reject( response.data.message ) );
            }
        );
    };

    return {
        getProducts : this.getProducts
    };
}]);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is worth to note that when I debug the code, I can see that messages and $scope.products arrays are populated. When I look at the generated page, I see a lot of empty div's created by the ng-repeat (100+), which is wrong since the return of the request is an array of 5 elements.

Answer (score 0):

The resolve injects data into the controller as a string. JSON.parse(messages) solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Would suggest doing the unpacking inside the service method (`getProducts()`).

The second function provided to $http is already returning a rejected promise so I would suggest just returning the data. i.e. `return response.data.message;` or rather `return JSON.parse(response.data.message);` if you need to unpack it the way you're suggesting.

Would also suggest if you have control of the backend service that you return with header `Content-Type: application/json` which will more accurately describe the payload and avoid this issue on the front end.

Answer (score 0):

Look like you forgot resolve for $q object at getProducts function.

You can try replace `return response.data;` by `$q.resolve(response.data);`

```
this.getProducts = function() {

    return $http.get("/products").then(
        function( response ) {
            $q.resolve(response.data);
        },
        function( response ) {

            if(!angular.isObject( response.data ) ) {
                console.log('unknown error');
                return ( $q.reject( "An unknown error ocurred." ) );
            }       

            console.log(response.data.message);
            return ( $q.reject( response.data.message ) );
        }
    );
};
```